# Accessing and outputing private vector

Tags: c++, class, vector

Straight to the point, im trying to output the values of a vector stored as private in a class but its not outputting anything.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>


using namespace std;

class logic {

public:
    void setVector(vector <int> aa){a = aa;}
    void setVector1(vector<int> bb){bb = b;}

     vector<int> &getVector(){return a;}
     vector <int> &getVector1(){return b;}

    int logics(vector<int>&a, vector<int>&b);
    void printArrays(vector <int>a, vector <int>b);

private:
  vector <int> a;
  vector <int> b;



};

int logic::logics(vector<int> &a, vector<int> &b){


    int r;
    while(cin >> r){
        for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
            a.push_back(r);
        }
        if(r < 0){break;}
    }

}

void logic::printArrays(vector<int> a, vector<int> b){
        cout << "im working!" << endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
            cout << a[i] << "\t";
        }

        for (vector <int>::iterator it = a.begin(); it < a.end(); it++){
            cout << *it << endl;
        }
}


int main()
{

    logic obj;

    obj.logics(obj.getVector(),obj.getVector1());
    obj.printArrays(obj.getVector(), obj.getVector1());

}
```

I have tried to make the vector constant as i've seen they are declared like this but the vector is being modified so i get an error. Ive also seen you can make vector of objects and classes like vector a but i dont gully understand it

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, it does,i actually have 2 vectors but i deleted the second one to make it easier to read. In my actual code inside the class is defined like this : void printArrays(vector <int>a, vector <int>b); I just forgot to delete it from the method when i posted the question.

Comment: This would be my full code. It compiles with no error,  inputs and shows "im working!" but doesnt print the vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `logics()`, if `a` is empty, this loop does nothing

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
  a.push_back(r);
}
```

so `a` remains empty.

On the other hand, if `a` was not empty, then it would blow up!
(each time we try to reach its size, this latter grows...)

Comment: Thanks i understood the size thing. I changed my loop to `i < 1` and works as intended.